# Aurelia Bundling with Sourcemaps undefined

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to debug my aurelia app and for some reason the sourcemap for my app bundle is being generated with the contents as 'undefined'.  Another strange thing is that all of my transpiled js files have a .map file except the bundle for all the aurelia libraries.

Here are some configs/gulp snippets, let me know if you need more details (I am running the latest version of everything, just ran npm update and jspm update):

ts.config

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./typings/index.d.ts",
    "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts",
    "./jspm_packages/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jspm_packages",
    "dist",
    "build"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

bundles.js

```
module.exports = {
  "bundles": {
    "dist/app-build": {
      "includes": [
        "[**/*.js]",
        "**/*.html!text",
        "**/*.css!text"
      ],
      "options": {
        "sourceMaps": 'inline',
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": true,
        "rev": true
      }
    },
    "dist/aurelia": {
      "includes": [
        "aurelia-framework",
        "aurelia-dialog",
        "aurelia-api",
        "aurelia-authentication",
        "aurelia-bootstrapper",
        "aurelia-fetch-client",
        "aurelia-router",
        "aurelia-animator-css",
        "aurelia-templating-binding",
        "aurelia-polyfills",
        "aurelia-templating-resources",
        "aurelia-templating-router",
        "aurelia-loader-default",
        "aurelia-history-browser",
        "aurelia-logging-console",
        "isomorphic-fetch",
        "polymer/mutationobservers",
        "moment",
        "numeral",
        "servicestack-client",
        "bootstrap",
        "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css!text",
        "bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css!text",
        "jquery",
        "text",
        "core-js"
      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": false,
        "rev": true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

build.js

```
var typescriptCompiler = typescriptCompiler || null;
gulp.task('build-system', function() {
  if(!typescriptCompiler) {
    typescriptCompiler = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
      "typescript": require('typescript')
    });
  }

  return gulp.src(paths.dtsSrc.concat(paths.source))
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError('Error: <%= error.message %>')}))
    .pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.ts'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(gulpif(common.serverNameOverrideCondition, replace(args.uriRegex, args.productionServerName)))
    .pipe(typescriptCompiler())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '/src' }).on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});
```

Any help would be appreciated like how can I debug this?

Comment: Isn't the problem the option: "sourceMaps": 'inline' ? Please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps

Comment: If I remove that line, I get a bunch of errors:  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat

Comment: Also, despite that inline statement, I still have valid map files generated for all the typescript files within the bundle and the bundle itself gets a map file to, it just contains one word: undefined.

Comment: Looking at the bundled file, it looks like there are two entries at the bottom, one that is the inline encoded sourcemap (//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64, ...) and another entry that points to a file: //# sourceMappingURL=app-build-019e5c2865.js.map.  When I look at an older build (before I did updates) I notice it did not have this second file mapping.  I suspect this is the problem, how do I stop this from being put in?

Comment: Just as a test, I removed the second entry by hand and it did in fact fix the problem with chrome looking for the 'undefined' source map.  The problem now is that the sourcemap contains the transpiled javascript and not the original typescript (like it used to).  Any idea how I can: a) stop the erroneous extra sourcemap url. b) have the source map include the original typescript?

Comment: Ok figured out b).  In my desperate attempt to fix a) I commented out ".pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))" based on another post with similar problems.  However this caused the TS files not to be included.  So now back to a)  How do I prevent 2 sourcemap urls.

Comment: Okay so it looks like it's a bug with the Aurelia-Bundler.  The version I was using prior to my update was 0.4.0 and as of 0.5.0 and persisting into 0.6.0 there is a bug where the bundler creates this invalid map file and adds a second sourcemap URL to the bundled js file.  I have reverted to 0.4.0 as a result.